# How to use Indian currency symbol in HTML?

Tags: website-design, css, html, character

I need to use the Indian Rupee symbol on a web page. I have applied the code `&#8377;`, but the output is `₹`. How to display Indian Rupee symbol on a website as text?

[image: Indian Rupee]

Comment: You realise the "I have applied..." and "the output is..." in your question both render the character correctly right?

Comment: I've made some edits to explicitly show the HTML code you're using (rather than it actually rendering the character), but you'll need to clarify because your output is appearing correct (to me at least). Maybe add a screenshot of what you are seeing.

Comment: This question belongs more to StackOverflow than here, and there is insufficient data in the question. The problem is most probably a font issue. Cf. http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=indian+rupee

Answer (score 4):

You can use decimal or hexadecimal values such as below.
Make you your meta charset is correctly set (UTF-8 should do I guess)

```
Decimal:     &#8377;
Hexadecimal: &#x20B9;
CSS code:    \20B9
```

More information and example usage on [this page](http://htmlarrows.com/currency/indian-rupee-sign/).

Comment: And the font used will need to contain that character.

Comment: i have checked that link but same issue. Please check the link https://snag.gy/BvsSVO.jpg

Comment: Then you need to install a font that actually *contains* that glyph. There is nothing we can do about that.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you're using Windows 7 version. An update to support Indian rupee sign is being rolled out by Microsoft  for Windows Vista, in Windows Server 2008, in Windows 7 and in Windows Server 2008 R2.

This update includes font support, locale changes, and keyboard support. 
Here's the [link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/2496898/an-update-to-support-the-new-currency-symbol-for-the-indian-rupee-in-windows-vista,-in-windows-server-2008,-in-windows-7-and-in-windows-server-2008-r2)